# Split backorder Orders in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, backorder

The website I am currently working on needs to separate orders in stock and orders in backorder. For example, when customer buys 1 in stock item and 1 backordered item, in the backend, there needs to be a separate orders with the ones in stock and backorder. I bought the extension Split order http://www.mlx-store.com/magento-extensions/sales/split-order-for-magento.html and it does the job I need it to do, but it can only separate 1 backorder. For example, when a customer buys 1 in stock item and 4 backorder items, when you go into the backend, only one of the backorder item is separated.

Is there any way to fix this extension or any other way to create an extension that will do the job that I need?

Thank you!